# Angularjs filter array based on a property which is of type Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks similar to this:

```
$scope.contracts = [
 {
  name: "contract1",
  partners : [{name: "John", age:"21"}, {name: "Peter", age: "33"}]
 },
 {
  name: "contract2",
  partners : [{name: "George", age:"51"}, {name: "Jack", age: "42"}]
 }
];
```

How can I filter `$scope.contracts` based on the name of a partner in HTML?
e.g. `ng-repeat="contract in contracts | filter : {partner: {name: 'John'}}"`. Here I should get the first contract but I have an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its typo `partner` should be `partners` inside filter.

```
ng-repeat="contract in contracts | filter : {partners: {name: 'John'}}"
```